# $_GET in Zend Framework

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I am a beginner in the Zend Framework.  I am passing a variable through ajax query like this

```
$.ajax({
     method: "GET",
     url: "/filename/fetch-client-data.php",
            dataType: 'json',
     // and so on
}
```

I need to get the variable passed by the form. I dont know how to use the $_GET['varaible name'] from the jquery.ajax.

Here is what I am trying in the controller function

```
 public function fetchClientDataAction()
 {
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
    $this->get('variablename')=$variable_name;
 }
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the super global $_GET in PHP like this:-

```
public function fetchClientDataAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
    $variable_name = $_GET['variable_name'];
}
```

There is a more 'Zend Framework' like way of doing it:-

```
$variable_name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('variable_name');
```

Obviously you will need to sanitise the data you receive as appropriate to your use case.

If you are asking about sending data back to the client to be processed, by jQuery, then you don't need to worry about $_GET or $_POST. You simply send your data as json in the body of the response:-

```
public function fetchClientDataAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
    $variable_name = $_GET['variable_name'];
    //now we can respond
    $result = doSomethingWithVariable_name($variable_name);
    header('OK', true, 200);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vascowhite..the output of json returns something like
[{"client_name":"Steve Harris","state":"TX"}]
is it because of the [] brackets it does not get displayed in the form?

Comment: str_replace( array( '[', ']'), '', json_encode($this->view->lead_query))
the above code worked for me